# Transcendence degree and dimension

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I  try   to  find  some  notes   where  is   proved  the  equivalence  between the   transcendence  degree  and  the  dimension  of  a  variety. In  my  course  the     dimension  is  define  as  the  maximal   lenght  of  ascending  chain  of  irreducible subvarieties. Can  you  help  me? Thank you!

Comment: I think this definition should be the length of a maximal chain of _closed_ irreducible subvarieties.

Comment: The equivalent statements in commutative algebra are given in Chapter 11 of Atiyah Macdonald